# In $\mathbb{Z_2[x]}/(x^2 + x +1)$, what is $\overline{x} \cdot \overline{x}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

In $\mathbb{Z_2[x]}/(x^2 + x +1)$, what is $\overline{x} \cdot \overline{x}$?

$\overline{x} \cdot \overline{x} = \overline{x^2}$

If I divide $\overline{x^2}$ by $(x^2 + x +1)$ I get an answer of $1$ with remainder $(-x-1)$.

$\overline{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ is $\overline{1}$

and

$\overline{-x}$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ is $\overline{x}$

So $\overline{x} \cdot \overline{x} = \overline{x + 1}$

Have I got that right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: It may be clearer to use $u=\bar x$ and $u^2+u+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$\overline{x^2 + x + 1} = \overline 0$$ since $x^2 + x + 1 \in (x^2 + x + 1)$, which means that $$\overline{x^2} =\overline{ - (x + 1)},$$ but since $-1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2,$ we get $$\overline{x^2} = \overline{x + 1}.$$